# zsh: bash script comparison of dynamically generated string

Tags: bash, zsh

This works as expected:-

```
x="None of the specified ports are installed"
if [ "$x" = "None of the specified ports are installed" ]; 
    then echo 1; 
    else echo 0; 
fi
```

I get `1`, which is what I am expecting.

But this does not work:-

```
y="`port installed abc`"
if [ "$y" = "None of the specified ports are installed" ]; 
    then echo 1; 
    else echo 0; 
fi
```

I get `0`, which is not what I am expecting; even though

```
echo $y
```

gives `None of the specified ports are installed.`

The main difference here is that `$y` is dynamically determined by the `port installed abc` command. But why would that affect my comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice carefully.

```
None of the specified ports are installed
```

not equal

```
None of the specified ports are installed.
                                         ^
                                        /
                          right there --
```

Another option

```
y=$(port installed abc)
z='None of the specified ports are installed'
if [[ $y =~ $z ]]
then
  echo 1
else
  echo 0
fi
```

Comment: O my, this is a careless mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach which is less sensitive to careless mistakes like missing out a "."

```
y="`port installed abc`"
if [[ "$y" = *"None of the specified ports are installed"* ]]; 
    then echo 1; 
    else echo 0; 
fi
```

Using the `[[ ]]` gives a more powerful comparison statement.

Also instead of using

```
y="`port installed abc`"
```

it is better to write

```
y=$(port installed abc)
```

Just some findings from a discussion with other developers on the bash irc channel.